# The motivation for defining Brouwer degree as $\deg(F,\Omega, y_0)= \sum_{x\in F^{-1}(y_0)} \operatorname{sign} J_{F(x)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

Brouwer degree is defined as 
$$\deg(F,\Omega, y_0)= \sum_{x\in F^{-1}(y_0)} \operatorname{sign} J_{F(x)}$$
This definition can be traced back to the paper of Nagumo 1951. I am wondering why we want to define it in this way, why we can’t instead define $t$ as the number of solutions

Comment: Because then this would not be 1) Independent of choice of $y_0$; 2) a homotopy invariant -- maybe the whole reason why degree is useful! The cancellation coming from counting with signs allows 1 and 2 to be true.